# How to stop to convert all my UIView controller in single size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, size-classes

As I have upgraded my Xcode with the latest version `8.0` while I am opening any Storyboard it's asking me to **choose device** like below screen shot.

It's a compulsory thing in `Xcode 8.0` so we are not refusing because there are only 2 buttons.

**Choose device** & **Close document**

So there is no way to revert back or edit your storyboard without this.

[image]

As my app is only supported in iPad Pro 12.9 so I am selecting that device.

Now there are lots of size update warning with yellow color in many of my `ViewController` interfaces. That's not a big issue, I will update that with option 'update frame' but many of my `ViewController` don't want to convert it into iPad Pro size.

Is there any way to **not convert all my `ViewController` into iPad Pro size** as I have many small size popups and inner views to show on the screen.

How to stop force converting the whole storyboard into respective device size?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Select your `UIViewController` --> `Attributes inspector` --> set size - `Inferred` to `Freeform`. And now you can set height - width from `Size inspector`.

Comment: yes I know this option but I have 70-80 `Viewcontroller` and  I don't want to do it manually its very time consuming. so my question is is there any way to not convert whole `storyboard` into particular size.

Comment: like bhavin said, your only choice is to convert the ones you need to be smaller manually. This stupid Xcode 8 forces all screen in storyboard the same size. I am hoping this will be fixed in next point release of Xcode 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per new `Xcode` update you can not stop this option or not ignore bcus without converting in single size it will not allow you to open `storyboard`

So for that you have to do one extra efforts on this part.

**1st way :-**

1. Open your storyboad in lower version
2. Go to viewController and in property inspector set size as **Freefrom** and

Do the same step for all ViewController and now you can open same storyboard with selected option like **iPhone 6 or iPhone 5** and see your all ViewController size not change and you can view all size as it is.

But one more option here

**2nd way : -** Create one new storyboard in new XCode and open old storyboard into older version of XCode and copy all your UIVC from there to here and it will work as expected.

Thanks.